# how to load xml from this code please

Tags: php, xml, load

I want to load the inside values from this xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<geoPlugin>
    <geoplugin_city>Salt Lake City</geoplugin_city>
    <geoplugin_region>UT</geoplugin_region>
    <geoplugin_areaCode>801</geoplugin_areaCode>
    <geoplugin_dmaCode>770</geoplugin_dmaCode>
    <geoplugin_countryCode>US</geoplugin_countryCode>
    <geoplugin_countryName>United States</geoplugin_countryName>
    <geoplugin_continentCode>NA</geoplugin_continentCode>
    <geoplugin_latitude>40.700199127197</geoplugin_latitude>
    <geoplugin_longitude>-111.94339752197</geoplugin_longitude>
    <geoplugin_regionCode>UT</geoplugin_regionCode>
    <geoplugin_regionName>Utah</geoplugin_regionName>
    <geoplugin_currencyCode>USD</geoplugin_currencyCode>
    <geoplugin_currencySymbol>&#36;</geoplugin_currencySymbol>
    <geoplugin_currencyConverter>1</geoplugin_currencyConverter>
</geoPlugin>
```

If you can see the geoplugin_city, etc
I want to load these values to php

```
$location = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($location);
```

that didn't work.
please help me out.

opps php i ment xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this first

```
$location = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($location);
```

After that, make a `Foreach` loop to have all the data from that.

```
foreach ($xml as $keys => $values) {
     $data[] = $values; // $data array have all your data independently.
}
```

Now, print the array and test the values.

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";
```

However, try for dumping the variables so you will get the data types too..

```
var_dump($xml);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not outputting XML, it's outputting serialized PHP data:

```
$location = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=192.168.1.1';
$file = unserialize(file_get_contents($location));
print_r($file);
```

Comment: It not working because he is not suppose to use `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call the xml API the URL is

```
$location = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($location);
```

Output Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<geoPlugin>
    <geoplugin_city>Lagos</geoplugin_city>
    <geoplugin_region>Lagos</geoplugin_region>
    <geoplugin_areaCode>0</geoplugin_areaCode>
    <geoplugin_dmaCode>0</geoplugin_dmaCode>
    <geoplugin_countryCode>NG</geoplugin_countryCode>
    <geoplugin_countryName>Nigeria</geoplugin_countryName>
    <geoplugin_continentCode>AF</geoplugin_continentCode>
    <geoplugin_latitude>6.4531002044678</geoplugin_latitude>
    <geoplugin_longitude>3.395800113678</geoplugin_longitude>
    <geoplugin_regionCode>05</geoplugin_regionCode>
    <geoplugin_regionName>Lagos</geoplugin_regionName>
    <geoplugin_currencyCode>NGN</geoplugin_currencyCode>
    <geoplugin_currencySymbol>&#8358;</geoplugin_currencySymbol>
    <geoplugin_currencyConverter>157.6899963379</geoplugin_currencyConverter>
</geoPlugin>
```

**EDIT 1**

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach($xml as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key , " = " , $value , "\n" ;
}
```

Output

```
geoplugin_city = Lagos
geoplugin_region = Lagos
geoplugin_areaCode = 0
geoplugin_dmaCode = 0
geoplugin_countryCode = NG
geoplugin_countryName = Nigeria
geoplugin_continentCode = AF
geoplugin_latitude = 6.4531002044678
geoplugin_longitude = 3.395800113678
geoplugin_regionCode = 05
geoplugin_regionName = Lagos
geoplugin_currencyCode = NGN
geoplugin_currencySymbol = ₦
geoplugin_currencyConverter = 157.6899963379
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: ok but now i want each value separated from the xml so i can use in php

Comment: Use `$xml->geoplugin_city` for city value alone

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the XML api instead of the PHP api.

```
$location = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($location);
```

Comment: yes, that's what i was working with
but now i need each value alone

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values in PHP, I would recommend not using the XML library at all.

```
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gpip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
//Then access the data directly.
echo $data['geoplugin_city'];
echo $data['geoplugin_region'];
```